# Wolfenstein Enemy Territory sound not working

Tags: 14.04, sound

I've tried all kinds of different solutions, but I just can't seem to get this game's sound to work. I'm kind of new to Ubuntu. I am using 14.04. Help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all the things you have tried. No point saying you've tried stuff unless you tell us what or you'll just get a whole load of answers that suggest what you've already done.

Comment: I've tried downloading wolfsp-sdl-sound.sh and executing that but it didn't work, I've tried the killall esd thing. I've tried sudo apt-get install esound.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the 32bit SDL library:
`sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian:i386`

if it doesn't work - make sure ET points to the right location. 
`sudo nano et` -> go to line ~11. and make sure that path is correct. You can locate the path by running `locate libSDL-1.2.so.0`